# Help OPENSLL-1.0.2

Tags: xubuntu, syslinux

I have a problem. I want to install the OPENSSL-1.0.2. But when I do that the problem appears that I don't know what OS/compiler to chose from the list witch opens in terminal. There are 100 chaise but I don't know what compiler to choose. Can some one help me?

Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
wget ftp://ftp.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2.tar.gz
tar xvzf openssl-1.0.2.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2/
./config
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply install OpenSSL through the repositories with

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

Comment: The version in the repo is 1.0.1f